# Using parent component data in child component Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-spark

I am using Laravel Spark, and have a component within a component.

```
<parent-component :user="user">

   <child-component :user="user" :questions="questions"></child-component>

<parent-component>
```

In my parent component I have questions data in my data method:

```
props: ['user'],
data(){
    return {
        questions: {
            // these are set in another method in this file
        },
    }
},
```

As you can see, I have added :questions to my child component in the hope of being able to use the questions in that component as I need to loop through them.

In my js file for the child component I have:

```
props: ['user', 'questions'],
```

But when trying to use the questions I get a default object unlike the user which contains all the information.

How should this be done correctly as im just guessing currently...

Here is the js file for the child component:

```
Vue.component('control-question-navigation', {
    props: ['user', 'questions'],
    data() {
        return {
        //
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted() {
        var $this = this;
        console.log($this.questions); // return standard object
        console.log($this.user); // returns the user data correctly
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your `child-component` and how are you viewing questions?

Comment: @saurabh Updated the question to show the js file. I can access the question data in my inline template but not in my js.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with the compilation scope for templates.

You seem to be using something called [**Content Distribution with Slots**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots), but with incorrect scoping for template variables.

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope

Quote from the page:

> A simple rule of thumb for component scope is:
>
> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in child scope.

I assume the following lines of template belongs to your root component:

```html
<div id="app">
    <parent-component :user="user">
       <child-component :user="user" :questions="questions"></child-component>
    <parent-component>
</div>
```

Here, user is already in root component, and therefore it is available to both `parent-component` and `child-component`. But your `questions` is defined in `parent-component`, and not in `root`.

As per the compilation scope docs in the link above, you should have `questions` also in the root component, along with `user`. Or else you should move your parent component template to its own vue file or into the template string of parent-component definition.

**EDIT: Possible solutions for clarity**

**Option 1**: You can define your root component, and include `questions` also in it along with `user`:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        user: "test user",
        questions: ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
});
```

The above root component will make both `user` and `questions` available to both `parent-component` and `child-component`.

**Option 2**: You can avoid using **Content Distribution with Slots** and instead use a template string:

```js
Vue.component("parent-component", {
    template: `
        <child-component :user="user" :questions="questions"></child-component>
    `,
    props: ["user"],
    data: function() {
        return {
            questions: {} // You can initialize this in a local method here
        }
    }
    // ...
})
```

Now your `child-component` will be able to get `this.questions` belonging to your `parent-component`

Comment: Excellent response it make sense. Ill have a read around and think about another method of achieving this.

Comment: I have extended my answer with two options to correct this issue. It can be fixed easily, assuming this is the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Ill take a look and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    questions: {
>         // these are set in another method in this file
>     }
> ```

You want to use a computed property.

```
computed: {
  questions(){ return this.anotherMethodInThisFile() }
},
methods: {
  anotherMethodInThisFile(){ return /* many questions */ }
}
```

Then alter the method to return the list of questions instead of changing component data and you're done. The template is correct, you just put the logic in the slightly wrong place.